# Portion of custom select file button for Fine uploader does not recognize click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I'm implementing something like the Google Plus' upload window, where when the entire gray area (a div) in the window is clickable and the file selector will appear. 
[image: Google Plus Photo Upload]

Here is a simplistic mockup code of what I'm trying to do ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xJXg/1/))

```
$(function () {
  var fineupper = new qq.FineUploader({
     element: $('#fine-uploader-container')[0],
     button: $('#clickable-area')[0],
     text: {
         uploadButton: 'click me'
     },
     request: {
         endpoint: '/example'
     },
     multiple: false
   });
 });

<body>
  <div id="upload-container" class="window">
    <div id="clickable-area" class="clickable-area">Click me</div>
  </div>
  <div id="fine-uploader-container"></div>
</body>
```

I'm seeing two problems:
1) The bottom portion of my 'clickable-area' div is not clickable.
2) The css for my 'clickable-area' div is getting modified. In particular the position attribute is getting overwritten as 'relative'.  (It's not so important in the jsfiddle, but more necessary in my real code)

Is there a way to get around these two issues?

Note that this is a continuation of [feature request 930](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/930)), where I requested to make my clickable-area div a label that references the input element. I personally still think this is a cleaner way of implementing a customizable button.

Also note that I've tried having javascript catch the click event of the clickable-area div and have it click the input element. However, as I'm trying for IE compatibility, this was [not doable](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/162).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realized I can add an id to the input element via jquery.  That enables me to make my container a label, so its css does not get modified by Fineuploader.  (It also allows the cursor to be consistent)

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xJXg/4/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="window">
    <label for="qqfile" id="container" class="container"></label>
    </div>
  <div id="fine-uploader-container"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.window {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
```

JS

```
$(function () {
  var fineupper = new qq.FineUploader({
    element: $('#fine-uploader-container')[0],
    text: {
      uploadButton: ''
    },
    request: {
      endpoint: '/example'
    },
    multiple: false
  });
  $('input[name="qqfile"]').attr('id', 'qqfile');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I misunderstand what you are asking. I modified your code a bit, and I believe I got basically what you were asking for to work.

The click handler on the uploader button is called on the file `input` element that FineUploader places in it's inner-DOM. By expanding that element to take up the entire space of its parent, you can register clicks on a larger area.

## HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
    <div id="fine-uploader">
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.container { width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: #ccc }
.container > input { width: 100%; height: 100% }
```

## JS

```
$(function () {
    var fineupper = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: $('#fine-uploader')[0],
        button: $(".container")[0],
        text: {
            uploadButton: 'click me'
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: '/upload/receiver'
        },
        multiple: false,
        dragAndDrop: {
        disableDefaultDropzone: true,
        hideDropzones: false,
            extraDropzones: [$(".container")[0]]
        },

    });
});
```

I've tested this in latest Chrome beta and Internet Explorers 7-10. Here's a corresponding **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xJXg/2/)**

Comment: This half answers my question - you can click anywhere on the container div and it brings up the file selector.

Comment: The other half is the overriding of the css position attribute.  Also, I noticed that the mouse cursor is not consistently a pointer when hovering over the top portion of the container div.  Any tricks around this?

Comment: Appreciate your time in looking at this. As indicated by my answer above, I've decided to do a slightly different approach to solve my issue.